# how to put multiple cols into long format base on suffix of variable names

Tags: r

I have wide df with multiple measurements. I would like to change wide to long. How should I do this. I know how to do 2 cols, but not multiples. Could someone guide me on this?
Input on the top, and ideal output on the bottom:

[image]

[image]

```
df<-structure(list(Subject = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
"Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Jerry", "Jerry", "Jerry", "Jerry", "Jerry"
), VSWGT_RAW = c(54.8, 55.6, 54.6, NA, 55.5, 55.7, 58.3, 60.7, 
66.4, 66.4, NA, 65.5, 65.2), VSWGT_UN = c("kg", "kg", "kg", NA, 
"kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", "kg", NA, "kg", "kg"), VSWGT_STD = c(54.8, 
55.6, 54.6, NA, 55.5, 55.7, 58.3, 60.7, 66.4, 66.4, NA, 65.5, 
65.2), VSWGT_STD_UN = c("kg", "kg", "kg", NA, "kg", "kg", "kg", 
"kg", "kg", "kg", NA, "kg", "kg"), VSHT_RAW = c(161, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 181, NA, NA, NA), VSHT_UN = c("cm", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "cm", NA, NA, NA), VSHT_STD = c(161, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 181, NA, NA, NA), VSHT_STD_UN = c("cm", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "cm", NA, NA, NA), VSRRATE_RAW = c("19", 
"13", "ND", "15", "14", "16", "9", "16", "12", "30", "14", "15", 
"16"), VSSYSBP = c(115, 115, 104, 103, 111, 113, 138, 146, 102, 
87, 103, 132, 132), date = structure(c(1655078400, 1655337600, 
1660521600, 1655424000, 1655942400, 1656547200, 1657152000, 1657756800, 
1674691200, 1673827200, 1674777600, 1675296000, 1675900800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What is the difference between the first table and the second table? It seems you just changed the names. Thats it

Comment: @onyambu the "Test" variable in the second table used to be in the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `names_sep` argument of `pivot_longer`, in combination with using the special `.value` token in `names_to`. I did have to change two things:

- Change variable names to only include 1 underscore, for easier separation.
- Make sure types match.

```
library(tidyverse)
    
df %>% 
  rename(VSWGT_STD.UN = VSWGT_STD_UN, VSHT_STD.UN = VSHT_STD_UN) %>% 
  mutate(VSRRATE_RAW = as.numeric(VSRRATE_RAW)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(Subject, date), names_sep = '_', names_to = c('test', '.value'))
```

Yields:

```
# A tibble: 52 × 7
   Subject date                test      RAW UN      STD STD.UN
   <chr>   <dttm>              <chr>   <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
 1 Tom     2022-06-13 00:00:00 VSWGT    54.8 kg     54.8 kg    
 2 Tom     2022-06-13 00:00:00 VSHT    161   cm    161   cm    
 3 Tom     2022-06-13 00:00:00 VSRRATE  19   NA     NA   NA    
 4 Tom     2022-06-13 00:00:00 VSSYSBP  NA   NA     NA   NA    
 5 Tom     2022-06-16 00:00:00 VSWGT    55.6 kg     55.6 kg    
 6 Tom     2022-06-16 00:00:00 VSHT     NA   NA     NA   NA    
 7 Tom     2022-06-16 00:00:00 VSRRATE  13   NA     NA   NA    
 8 Tom     2022-06-16 00:00:00 VSSYSBP  NA   NA     NA   NA    
 9 Tom     2022-08-15 00:00:00 VSWGT    54.6 kg     54.6 kg    
10 Tom     2022-08-15 00:00:00 VSHT     NA   NA     NA   NA
```

Comment: This is a very neat!

Comment: Is it possible to rename variables in  batch in stead one by one?

Comment: Sure, see the examples at `?rename`.